# missing month count from the datetime column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Existing Dataframe :

```
      Id         Date_of_activity   
    
       A        2020-09-17 12:36:00     
       A        2020-11-02 00:00:00     
       A        2020-12-02 00:00:00     
       A        2021-01-02 00:00:00     
       A        2021-02-02 00:00:00 
       A        2021-03-03 12:12:00     
       A        2021-04-03 12:12:00     
    
       B        2020-11-02 00:00:00         
       B        2021-01-02 00:00:00         
       B        2021-03-03 12:12:00     
       B        2021-04-03 12:12:00
```

Expected Dataframe :

```
  Id      Missed_Month_Count
  A              1
  B              2
```

I am looking to calculate the Number of Missed Months where NO activity was Done.
For Id A , No activity was done in 10th Month of 2020 so the missed month count should be 1 , likewise for B , No activity was done in 12th month of 2020 and 2nd month of 2021 , which makes missed_month_count as 2.

Comment: What did you try to get the missing month count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
# convert to Monthly period
s = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_of_activity']).dt.to_period('M')

# compute the difference per group
# if != 1, then there is a missing month
out = (s.sort_values()
        .groupby(df['Id'], sort=False)
        .apply(lambda g: g.drop_duplicates().diff().ne('M').sum()-1)
        .reset_index(name='Missed_Month_Count')
      )
```

output:

```
  Id  Missed_Month_Count
0  A                   1
1  B                   2
```

Comment: thanks.! will this work if same month is repeated with different activity date. i mean for Id A if  after 2021-04-03 , if there would have been 2021-04-12 , will the output remain same..?